# Using ReactDOM with different namespace

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use `ReactDOM` in a non-html workspace. So the elements need to be made like this:

```
document.createElementNS('namespace here', '...')
```

This is how we normally do stuff with ReactDOM:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

How can I make it so that the `h1` is in a different namespace?

Like is it possible to do:

`ReactElement.createElementNS`? Which would be same like `ReactElement.createElement` except with a namespace?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean “different namespace”? You want the output to ultimately be e.g. `<somens:h1>`?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMarshall ! I need to create things with XUL namespace, so `var xulVbox = browserWindow1.document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'vbox');` here are some documentations - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.createElementNS